# Node specific attributes in chef

Tags: chef-infra

I am setting up chef server for the first time, and wondering where I should store **configuration information** that is unique to each node.  For example, each server will have an application that contains client specific information, but this information is different for each server.  I need a mapping that would look something like this:

```
node1 : application1 : client1,client2,client3
node2 : application1 : client3,client5,client9
node3 : application1 : client1,client7,client8
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can put this information inside the node configuration itself.

So, inside `nodes/node1-hostname.json` you would have:

```
{
    "application1": {
        "clients": ["client1", "client2", "client3"],
    },
    "run_list": [
        "recipe[webserver]",
        "recipe[your_recipe]"
    ]
}
```

Then inside `nodes/node2-hostname.json` and `nodes/node3-hostname.json` you would have their specific configuration.

Comment: Should this work for chef-server as well as chef-solo?  When I upload to chef-server from the node.json file, the run_lists show up, but the new attributes do not.  I verified this from the chef-shell.

Comment: The format is a bit different depending on how you are uploading it. Try putting the node attributes under a `"normal"` key.